# Acronyms of catalogs in SIMBAD database

Tags: fundamental-astronomy, data-analysis

How to find acronym of specific catalog in [SIMBAD](http://simbad.u-strasbg.fr/simbad/) database? For example, I want to select 
stellar names, object types and all binary stars from "Stellar effective magnetic fields. II." catalog (Bychkov+, 2009; J/MNRAS/394/1338) via [SIMBAD script page](http://simbad.u-strasbg.fr/simbad/sim-fscript). How to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's roughly like this:

```
set limit 100
format object form1 "%IDLIST(1) : %OTYPE(S)"
query sample (otypes = '*i*') & (bibcode='2009MNRAS.394.1338B')
```

To get the list of the bibcodes choose
"Other" / "Catalogue collection"
from the menue bar.
The screen should look like
[image: SIMBA1]

Then click the icon "Click to display the menu" at the left border:
[image: SIMBA2]

Here you find the bibcode:
[image]

Comment: perhaps you know where to find full list of SIMBAD catalogs acronyms like 'hip', 'ppm' etc. ?

Comment: @user2579566: Extended answer with info, how to access bibcodes.

Answer (score 2):

Click on the link "SIMBAD Objects (1224)" shown [in this page](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2009MNRAS.394.1338B)

It seems Simbad doesn't have an specific acronym for the stars studied by Bychkov et al, because I was unable to find such acronym using Simbad's [Dictionary of Nomenclature of Celestial Objects](http://cds.u-strasbg.fr/cgi-bin/Dic-Simbad).

Since I knew that ADS shows a Simbad link for some articles, I searched for articles written by Bychkov in 2009 using [The SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System Astronomy Query Form](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abstract_service.html). That's how I find the first link in this answer.

Comment: Thank you Bruno! I know this option, but I need to do this using [SIMBAD script page](http://simbad.u-strasbg.fr/simbad/sim-fscript) because of many reasons.

Comment: Then, why would you not try "query bibobj" or "*query bibcode" commands? They are listed under "List of query commands:" in the link you provided. Or else, you could use [ADQL](http://simbad.u-strasbg.fr/simbad/help/adqlHelp.html). Try it [here](http://tapvizier.u-strasbg.fr/adql/)